# The Method Of Frobenius

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, power-series, frobenius-method, fundamental-solution

> The ODE $xy'' + y = 0$ has a real degeneracy.  Use The Method Of
> Frobenius to find a fundamental set of solutions.

Here is the procedure, as I understand it:

**1)  Plug the guess $y = x^s \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n$ into the ODE and do the algebra/calculus to separate out the indicial equation and the recurrence relation.**

$xy'' + y = 0$
$x(x^s \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n)'' + (x^s \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n) = 0$
$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n x^{n + s - 1} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^{n + s} = 0$
$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n x^{n + s - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_{n - 1} x^{n + s - 1} = 0$
$s(s - 1) a_0 x^{s - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n x^{n + s - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_{n - 1} x^{n + s - 1} = 0$
$s(s - 1) a_0 x^{s - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n x^{n + s - 1} + a_{n - 1} x^{n + s - 1} = 0$
$s(s - 1) a_0 x^{s - 1} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty [(n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n + a_{n - 1}] x^{n + s - 1} = 0$

*Indicial Equation:*  $s(s - 1) = 0$
*Recurrence Relation:*  $(n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n + a_{n - 1} = 0$, where $n \geq 1$

**2)  Solve the recurrence relation, treating $s$ as a constant, but without plugging in any indicial equation solutions.**

$(n + s)(n + s - 1) a_n + a_{n - 1} = 0$
$a_n = -\frac{1}{(n + s)(n + s - 1)}a_{n - 1}$
$a_n = a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}$

Here I would simplify using a formula I was given, $\Pi_{j = c}^d (j + k) = \frac{(d + k)!}{(c + k - 1)!}$.

$a_n = a_0 [\Pi_{m = 1}^n -1] [\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s)}] [\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s - 1)}]$
$a_n = a_0 [(-1)^n] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s)!}{s!}}] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s - 1)!}{(s - 1)!}}]$
$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n s! (s - 1)!}{(n + s)! (n + s - 1)!} a_0$

**3)  To find one fundamental solution, plug the largest indicial equation solution $s_1$ and its associated recurrence relation solution into the guess, and make the particular choice $a_0 = 1$.**

$s(s - 1) = 0$
$s = 0, 1$
$s_1 = 1$
$y = x^1 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n 1! (1 - 1)!}{(n + 1)! (n + 1 - 1)!} 1 x^n$
$y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1}}{n! (n + 1)!}\leftarrow$  ***FIRST FUNDAMENTAL SOLUTION***

**4)  To find another fundamental solution, plug the other indicial equation solution $s_2$ and its associated recurrence relation solution into $y = [$FIRST FUNDAMENTAL SOLUTION$]ln|x| +\ x^{s_2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{\partial}{\partial s} ((s - s_2)a_n)]_{s = s_2} x^n$, and make the particular choice $a_0 = 1$.**

$s_2 = 0$

Here I use the earlier, less simplified expression for $a_n$ which is in $\Pi$ product notation, in anticipation of taking the logarithmic partial derivative.

$y = (\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1}}{n! (n + 1)!})ln|x| + x^0 \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{\partial}{\partial s} ((s - 0) a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})]_{s = 0} x^n$
$y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1} ln|x|}{n! (n + 1)!} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{\partial}{\partial s} (s a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})]_{s = 0} x^n$

I make the substitution $b_n = s a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}$, appearing in the solution as $y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1} ln|x|}{n! (n + 1)!}$
$+ \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{\partial}{\partial s} b_n]_{s = 0} x^n$.

$b_n = s a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}$
$ln|b_n| = ln|s| + ln|a_0| + \sum_{m = 1}^n ln|\frac{1}{m + s}| + ln|\frac{1}{1 - m - s}|$
$\frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|b_n| = \frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|s| + \frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|a_0| + \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|\frac{1}{m + s}| + \frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|\frac{1}{1 - m - s}|$

I set $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} ln|a_0|$ to $0$ because the chapter stipulates that this procedure only seeks solutions where $a_0$ is nonzero and does not depend on $s$.

$\frac{\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s}}{b_n} = \frac{1}{s} + 0 + \sum_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{m + s} + \frac{1}{1 - m - s}$
$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{b_n}{s} + b_n \sum_{m = 1}^n -\frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}$
$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{s a_0 \Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}}{s} + s a_0 (\Pi_{m = 1}^n -\frac{1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})(\sum_{m = 1}^n -\frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})$

Now I can simplify the $\Pi$ products using the above formula.  I also make the choice for $a_0$ here.

$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{s [\Pi_{m = 1}^n -1] [\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s)}] [\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s - 1)}]}{s} + s ([\Pi_{m = 1}^n -1] [\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s)}][\frac{1}{\Pi_{m = 1}^n (m + s - 1)}])(\sum_{m = 1}^n -\frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})$
$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{s [(-1)^n] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s)!}{s!}}] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s - 1)!}{(s - 1)!}}]}{s} + s ([(-1)^n] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s)!}{s!}}] [\frac{1}{\frac{(n + s - 1)!}{(s - 1)!}}])(\sum_{m = 1}^n -\frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)})$
$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{(-1)^n s! (s - 1)! + (-1)^{n + 1} s!^2 \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}}{(n + s)! (n + s - 1)!}$

Unwinding the substitution, I plug the expression for $\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s}$ back into the fundamental solution.

$y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1} ln|x|}{n! (n + 1)!} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{(-1)^n s! (s - 1)! + (-1)^{n + 1} s!^2 \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}}{(n + s)! (n + s - 1)!}]_{s = 0} x^n$
$y = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1} ln|x|}{n! (n + 1)!} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (-1)! x^n + (-1)^{n + 1} x^n \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m - 1}{m^2 - m}}{n! (n - 1)!}$

And now we see that something is broken.  $(-1)!$ is undefined, and can't even be rescued by being generalized to the Gamma or Pi function.  What am I doing wrong, and how can I use this method to solve this ODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first mistake is with the book/material you are using, as $$y_2 = y_1\ln|x| + u$$ isn't a valid solution of the differential equation if $u = x^{s_2} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty [\frac{\partial}{\partial s} ((s - s_2)a_n)]_{s = s_2} x^n$ and $a_0 = 1$. Instead, you either want $a_0 = -1$ or $y_2 = y_1\ln|x| - u$. Not a rigorous proof, but you can see evidence to support this by looking at the constant term of $xy_2'' + y_2$, which must be $0$.

The main problem is the hole at $s = 0$. You ended up with $$\frac{\partial b_n}{\partial s} = \frac{(-1)^n s! (s - 1)! + (-1)^{n + 1} s!^2 \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}}{(n + s)! (n + s - 1)!} \tag{*}$$ and directly plugged in $s = 0$. But the function is undefined there because of the $(-1)!$ term. Instead, take the limit as $s \to 0$. The limit is $1$ for $n = 0$ and $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2nH_{n-1})}{(n!)^2}$$  for $n \ge 1$, where $H_n$ is the harmonic number (found using Mathematica, proof at bottom). This means that the second solution is $$y_2 = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n + 1} \ln|x|}{n! (n + 1)!} - \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2nH_{n-1})}{(n!)^2} x^n\right)$$

Edit: Coming back to $(*)$: The problem is to evaluate $$\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{(-1)^n s! (s - 1)! + (-1)^{n + 1} s!^2 \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}}{(n + s)! (n + s - 1)!}$$ For $n = 0$, it is clearly $0$ since the sum is $0$ and then the numerator is the same as the denominator. For other $n$, we can factor it as $$\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{(-1)^ns!}{(n+s)!(n+s-1)!}\left( (s - 1)! - s! \sum_{m = 1}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}\right)$$ The factors converge separately, so moving the first term to the outside and splitting the sum makes it $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n-1)!}\lim_{s \to 0}\left( (s - 1)! -s! \frac{2s +1}{(1 + s)s}- s! \sum_{m = 2}^n \frac{2m + 2s - 1}{(m + s)(m + s - 1)}\right)$$ which is equal to $$-\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n-1)!}\lim_{s \to 0} \left(\frac{s!}{s+1}\right)-\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n-1)!}\left( \sum_{m = 2}^n \frac{2m - 1}{m(m - 1)}\right)$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^2}\left(n+n\sum_{m = 2}^n \left( \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m-1} \right)\right) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n!)^2}\left(1+2nH_{n-1}\right)$$

Edit 2: By the way, the solutions (found using Mathematica) are $$y_1 = \sqrt{x}\ J_1(2\sqrt{x}), y_2 = \sqrt{x}\ Y_1(2\sqrt{x})$$ where $J_1(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind, and $Y_1(z)$ is the Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: Hmmm, I was under the assumption that I was allowed to replace $a_0$ with any constant.  How is $a_0$ solved for when solving other similar equations?  Is it just always $1$ or $-1$ (depending on the $y_2$ formula you use), or does it need to be computed?

Comment: It couldn't be any constant - that would imply that any $y_2$ of the form $y_1\ln|x|+c\cdot u$ would work, which is impossible since the two linearly independent solutions are already given by $y_1$ and $y_1\ln|x|-u$. What does work is $a_0\left(y_1\ln|x| - u\right)$.

Comment: I forgot to say in my earlier comment, but the first coefficient of the series expansion of both $y_1$ and $u$ should be $1$ (or at least the same constant). This is what makes them "cancel" out when plugging into the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Just a pictorial comment. It's always nice to see what the outcome of a differential equation looks like.

[image]

And, by the way, it does not seem much of an effort to solve it numerically, for example as in the Pascal snippet below. The solution looks like a sine with decreasing frequency, as has to be expected. The MUCH parameter has been given two different values for checking convergence.

```
procedure test(much : integer);
var
  y : array of double;
  x,dx : double;
  k : integer;
begin
  SetLength(y,much+1);
  dx := (xmax-xmin)/much;
  y[0] := 0;
  y[1] := y[0] + dx;
  for k := 1 to much-1 do
  begin
    x := k*dx;
    y[k+1] := 2*y[k]-y[k-1]-sqr(dx)/x*y[k];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: More theory and free sourde code at: [__MSE publications / references 2021__](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2021/index.htm)